# NavigationBar and BackButton

Tags: swift, xcode6, alpha, back-button, navigationbar

I was coding today, and I saw the NavigationBar and I said "Why not setting the NavigationBar's alpha to 0.3". And I did it.

But now my back button has an alpha of 0.3 too! And I don't want that!

So, is there a way to set the NavigationBar's alpha to 0.3 without affecting the BackButton?

And by the way my code is made on Swift Language.

Comment: Which language? toolkit? OS?

Comment: My bad, it is Swift.